# Swift NSInternalInconsistencyException when reloading table section on Main Thread

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I have a `UITableView` which accesses its data indirectly (i.e. it is backed by a data structure of pointers) and asynchronously reloads its sections whenever new data is pulled from a remote server. It seems my reloading scheme has a race condition; even though I only perform my table view reloads on the main thread, I occasionally see the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

My code is structured as follows:

```
var table_data_indirect_1: [CustomDataPointer] = []
var table_data_indirect_2: [CustomDataPointer] = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let x = customData(in: indexPath.section)[indexPath.row], let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "custom-identifier", for: indexPath) as? CustomCell {
        cell.setCustomData(to: x)
        return cell
    } else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return customData(in: section).count
}

 func numberOfSections(in: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func customData(in section: Int) -> [CustomDataStruct] {        
    switch section {
    case 0:
        return table_data_indirect_1.map { asyncLoadCustomData($0, for: section) }
    case 1:            
        return table_data_indirect_2.map { asyncLoadCustomData($0, for: section) }
    default:
        return []
    }
}

func asyncLoadCustomData(_ customDataPointer: CustomDataPointer, for section: Int) -> CustomDataStruct {
    if customDataPointer.isLoaded {
        return customDataPointer.backingStruct
    } else {
        customDataPointer.asyncLoad { result in
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                let section_set = IndexSet(integersIn: section...section)
                self?.table.reloadSections(section_set, with: .none)
            }
        }
        return customDataPointer.placeholderStruct
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` methods.

Comment: Added to original post

Comment: According to the message shown, your `customDataPointer.asyncLoad` may be changing the contents of unspecified section. When you use `reloadSections(_:with:)`, you should not change the contents of other sections. Please check it.

Comment: asyncLoad does not touch the table in anyway - it simply spawns a networking request that fetches my customData from some server